# Parallel scraping with Cherio

Tags: promise, request, cheerio, request-promise

I am trying to **scrape** a website with multiple section and pagination in parallel. The idea is to go through each section per page.

For instance if there are 6 sections and each section has  6 items per page (total page is up to 10), then I would like the code to run at least 6 jobs in paralel.

Below is what I have

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request-promise');
const baseUrl = 'https://www.bankmega.com/';
let category = 0;
let page = 0;

(async function () {
    try {
        const homePage = baseUrl + '/promolainnya.php';
        const html = await request(homePage);
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const jobs = $('div[id="subcatpromo"]').find('img').map((i, img) => scrapePerCategory({title: $(img).attr('title'), category: i + 1}));
        await Promise.all(jobs); // error  TypeError: undefined is not a function
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error in main ', e);
    }
})();

const scrapePerCategory = async (job) => {
    try {
        let pageNumber;
        let i = 1;
        let result = [];
        console.log('start scraping for category ' + job.title);
        do {
            page = i;
            category = job.category;

            const url = baseUrl + `/ajax.promolainnya.php?product=1&subcat=${category}&page=${page}`;
            const html = await request(url);
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            if (!pageNumber) {
                pageNumber = $('a.page_promo_lain[id]').length;
            }
            const temp = $('#promolain').find('a').map(async (i, promoElem) => {
                const title = cheerio(promoElem).find('img').attr('title');
                const detailLink = cheerio(promoElem).attr('href');
                const detailHTML = await request(baseUrl + detailLink);
                const $ = cheerio.load(detailHTML);
                const imageurl = baseUrl + $('.keteranganinside').find('img').attr('src');
                console.log('category : ' + job.category + ' with item  => ' + JSON.stringify({title: title, imageurl: imageurl}));
                return {title: title, imageurl: imageurl};
            }).get();
            await Promise.all(temp).then(r => result.push(r));
            i++;
        } while (i <= pageNumber) ;
        await Promise.all(result).then((r) => "done scraping for category " + job.title);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error in category', e);
    }
};
```

It prints as expected when I run

```
start scraping for category Travel
start scraping for category Lifestyle
start scraping for category Food & Beverages
start scraping for category Gadget & Entertainment
start scraping for category Daily Needs
start scraping for category Others
category : 6 with item  => {"title":"Perubahan Minimum Payment","imageurl":"https://www.bankmega.com//files/images/minimum payment-lp- rev.jpg"}
category : 1 with item  => {"title":"Visa Bluebird Diskon hingga 25ribu","imageurl":"https://www.bankmega.com//files/images/0-landing-page-BLUE-BIRD.jpg"}
category : 6 with item  => {"title":"Aktivasi Kartu Kredit dan PIN","imageurl":"https://www.bankmega.com//files/images/AKTIVASI-CC-lp-CS5-revrainy.jpg"}
```

However when the caller (main method gives error) as follows

```
error in main  TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
```

It makes me wonder if code is indeed running as I expected or not.

Comment: There's no `console.log()` in the line `await Promise.all(result).then((r) => "done scraping for category " + job.title);`

Comment: A `.map()` callback is impervious to `await`.

Comment: Could you attempt to answer the Promise.all issue in both methods (the caller and the callee) ? I'd like to see the result in the main method @Roamer-1888

Comment: I'm attempting ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterative approach should work though discovering `pageNumber` on the first iteration makes it somewhat messy. Recursion should make it a lot tidier.

Not much time right now as I need to get out for my legal exercise, so here's a version of your iteration that stands a chance of working. You may well need to fix it here and there.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request-promise');
const baseUrl = 'https://www.bankmega.com/';

(async function () {
    try {
        const $ = cheerio.load(await request(baseUrl + '/promolainnya.php'));
        // map img elements to array of promises ...
        let promises = $('div[id="subcatpromo"]').find('img').get().map((img, i) => scrapePerCategory({'title': $(img).attr('title'), 'category': i + 1}));
        // ... and await the promises.
        const jobs = await Promise.all(promises);
        console.log(jobs);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error in main ', e);
    }
})();

const scrapePerCategory = async (job) => {
    try {
        let pageNumber;
        let page = 1; // both `page` and `i` counters seem unnecessary - one or the other?
        const results = [];
        do {
            let url = baseUrl + `/ajax.promolainnya.php?product=1&subcat=${job.category}&page=${page}`;
            let $ = cheerio.load(await request(url));
            if (!pageNumber) {
                pageNumber = $('a.page_promo_lain[id]').length;
            }
            // here compose `innerResults` in much the same way `results` is composed ...
            let innerResults = [];
            let anchors = $('#promolain').find('a');
            for(var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) { // for loop here allows `await` to await
                let promoElem = cheerio(anchors[i]);
                let $ = cheerio.load(await request(baseUrl + promoElem.attr('href')));
                innerResults.push({
                    'title': promoElem.find('img').attr('title'), 
                    'imageurl': baseUrl + $('.keteranganinside').find('img').attr('src')
                });
            }
            // ... and aggregate `innerResults` into `results`
            results.push(innerResults); // or results = results.concat(innerResults); ?
            page++;
        } while (page <= pageNumber);
        console.log("done scraping for category " + job.title);
        return results;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error in category', e);
        throw e;
    }
};
```